# Python: for loop - print on the same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, printing

I have a question about printing on the same line using `for` loop in Python 3. I searched for the answer but I couldn't find any relevant.

So, I have something like this:

```
def function(s):
    return s + 't'

item = input('Enter a sentence: ')

while item != '':
    split = item.split()
    for word in split:
        new_item = function(word)
        print(new_item)
    item = input('Enter a sentence: ')
```

When a user types in 'A short sentence', the function should do something with it and it should be printed on the same line.
Let's say that function adds 't' to the end of each word, so the output should be

```
At shortt sentencet
```

However, at the moment the output is:

```
At
shortt
sentencet
```

How can I print the result on the same line easily? Or should I make a new string so

```
new_string = ''
new_string = new_string + new_item
```

and it is iterated and at the end I print `new_string`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `end` parameter in the `print` function

```
print(new_item, end=" ")
```

There is another way to do this, using comprehension and `join`.

```
print (" ".join([function(word) for word in split]))
```

Answer (score 8):

The simplest solution is using a comma in your `print` statement:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...   print i,
...
0 1 2 3 4
```

Note that there's no trailing newline; `print` without arguments after the loop would add it.

Comment: Note this only works in Python 2, and OP seems to be using Python 3

Answer (score 2):

As `print` is a function in Python3, you can reduce your code to:

```
while item:
    split = item.split()
    print(*map(function, split), sep=' ')
    item = input('Enter a sentence: ')
```

**Demo:**

```
$ python3 so.py
Enter a sentence: a foo bar
at foot bart
```

---

Even better using [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) and [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
f = partial(input, 'Enter a sentence: ')

for item in iter(f, ''):
    split = item.split()
    print(*map(function, split), sep=' ')
```

**Demo:**

```
$ python3 so.py
Enter a sentence: a foo bar
at foot bart
Enter a sentence: a b c
at bt ct
Enter a sentence: 
$
```

Comment: I always had this doubt, can we use `iter` to stop when any of the items in a list is encountered?

Comment: @thefourtheye I don't think so, because we don't have access to `item` inside `iter`, but we can use `itertools.takewhile` for that.

Comment: @hcwhsa You mean we can combine `iter` and `takewhile` to do that?

Comment: Downvoter, could you please explain why?

Comment: @thefourtheye No, just `takewhile`: `for x in takewhile(lambda x: x not in my_list, (x() for x in repeat(f)))`, where `f` is `f = partial(input, 'Enter a sentence: ')`