# How do I output the acronym on one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am following the hands-on python tutorials from Loyola university and for one exercise I am supposed to get a phrase from the user, capatalize the first letter of each word and print the acronym on one line.

I have figured out how to print the acronym but I can't figure out how to print all the letters on one line.

```
    letters = []
    line = input('?:')
    letters.append(line)
    for l in line.split():
        print(l[0].upper())
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: for loop - print on the same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031734/python-for-loop-print-on-the-same-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `end=''` to your `print` function to suppress the newline character, viz:

```
for l in line.split():
    print(l[0].upper(), end='')
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question would be better if you shared the code you are using so far, I'm just guessing that you have saved the capital letters into a list.

You want the string method .join(), which takes a string separator before the . and then joins a list of items with that string separator between them. For an acronym you'd want empty quotes

e.g.

```
l = ['A','A','R','P']
acronym = ''.join(l)
print(acronym)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a string variable at the beginning `string = ""`.

Then instead of doing `print(l[0].upper())` just append to the string `string += #yourstuff`

Lastly, `print(string)`