# Interpolate sleep() and print() in the same line inside a for loop using python 3

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, sleep

I was trying to print the result of a loop in the same line using python 3 and after reading [Python: for loop - print on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031734/python-for-loop-print-on-the-same-line) I managed to do it.

```
for x in range(1,10):
    print(x, end="")
```

The problem now is when I insert

```
time.sleep(2)
```

before the print.
I would like to print the first character, wait two seconds, then the second, wait two more seconds, etc.

Here the code:

```
for x in range(1,10):
    time.sleep(2)
    print(x, end="")
```

With that we wait 20 seconds (= 10*2) and only then the numbers are displayed. This is not what we expect.

What I should do to have the above expected behavior, namely wait 2 seconds, print first character, wait more 2 seconds, print second character, etc.

Comment: Also see another duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411532/how-do-i-print-from-a-python-2-7-script-invoked-from-bash-within-pycharm/38411633).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output to `stdout` is line buffered, which means the buffer is not flushed until a newline is printed.

Explicitly flush the buffer each time you print:

```
print(x, end="", flush=True)
```

Demo:

[image: demonstration animation showing slowly-added digits at 2 second intervals]